# Nested views and events in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

So I have two views. One 'parent' view that is bound to a collection and a number of sub-views that are bound to individual models in the collection.

```
class ResultTable extends Backbone.View
    el:"body"
    initialize:()->
       @collection.bind "add", @add

    add:(model)->
       new ModelView({model:model})

class ModelView extends Backbone.View
    el: "#resultsTableList"
    initialize:()=>
       @model.on "selected",@select
       @render()

    render:()=>
       #append template 

    select:(e)=>
       e.preventDefault()
       console.log(@model)

    events:
       'click' : 'select'
```

So when I click on one of the list elements, all of the ModelViews' select functions get triggered. I thought the way I had built this only the specific model that had been clicked would show up. What's going on?

TEMPLATE HTML-

```
<div id="resultsTableContainer" class="resultsContainer">
    <ul id="resultsTableList">
    </ul>
```

THIS IS FOR EACH MODEL-

```
<li class="result">
{{ ipAddress }}


  </li>
```

Comment: Interesting, can you please share your template HTML? could it be that it's a e.stopPropagation vs e.preventDefault thing? is this all the code? like you I'm missing the reason. p.s. is this the original indentation? it looks like your select function belongs to the collection view and not the child view (I think coffeescript is sensitive to it, but I'm not a coffeescript user)

Comment: so I think you can assume the indentation is ok. I don't think this is the problem. There's one more part that(I don't think) is the problem, but I'll post it up. Also posting template html

Comment: hm.. where do you close the </li>? not sure it's related but it might be... also when you do "on" you don't seem to pass "this" as the context, so the context will be your model, not your view on ` @model.on "selected",@select`

Comment: so when I click elsewhere on the page the select function is triggered, meaning that for some reason the views are on top of each other and spread across the page? I have no clue if views can be geometrically limited on the page.

Comment: Eran- sorry I'm being stupid - could you rephrase your comment?

Comment: as in I thought I was passing in teh context with @model?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, I know it's not full but hard to do it in a comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your ModelViews are bound to the same DOM element:

```
class ModelView extends Backbone.View
    el: "#resultsTableList"
```

And then each instance will bind to clicks on `#resultsTableList`:

```
events:
   'click' : 'select'
```

Note that [specifying an event in `events` without a selector](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) binds it to the view's `el`:

> Omitting the `selector` causes the event to be bound to the view's root element (`this.el`).

The result is that you have multiple views binding to the clicks on the exact same DOM element.

I think you want to drop the `el` and from your ModelView and let Backbone build the `<li>` like this:

```
class ModelView extends Backbone.View
    tagName: 'li'
    className: 'result'
    #...
```

Then, the `el` for the `ModelView` will be an `<li class="result">` and the click handler will be attached to the `<li>`. You'll have to adjust the rendering to put the `el`s into the `<ul id="resultsTableList">` in the caller as well.

Comment: what do you mean by the part about adjusting rendering?

Comment: You'll need to do something like `$('#resultsTableList').append(model_view.render().el)` to get the `<li>`s into the DOM. And adjust the template so that it doesn't have the `<li>` in it, the per-ModelView template would be just `{{ ipAddress }}`.

Comment: oh so this should be in the parent view?

Comment: so what should my render method look like? Should it just append a template with {{ ipAddress }} ?

Comment: now...no click events are firing, so I'm not sure what's going on again.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, a demo would be useful (start here: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/JM5de/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I promised I'll explain my comment in an answer, although *mu is too short* got the right answer, but hopefully it will be of value to you as well

What I meant is that when binding, I would prefer using `listenTo` instead of `on` (to avoid zombie listeners) , but if you do use `on` then make sure you pass the context if you need to e.g.

```
this.model.on("selected", this.select);
```

v.s.

```
this.model.on("selected", this.select, this);
```

the first one has the `this` object bound to the `model`
the second has it bound to the `this` at the time you call it (the view)

So it all depends on what you want your `this` object to be in the `select` function body

(sorry it's not in CoffeeScript, I just don't know it that well)